# comparing a txt file with csv file with python

Tags: python

I am working on developing a python code that would compare a txt file and a csv file and find out if there are identical or not.If not,find the errors and summarize them on a excel table.

```
def main(): 
filename1=input("Enter txt file name:- ") 
filename2=input("Enter csv file name:- ")

fp1=open(filename1,"r") 
fp2=open(filename2,"r")

list1=[] 
list2=[]

for line in fp1: #iterating through each line in the file
   a=line.split(",") #splitting line based on comma
   for i in a: #iterating through each element in list
       i=i.rstrip() #removing new line from elements in list
       list1.append(i) #appending element in the list

for line in fp2:
   a=line.split(",")
   for i in a:
       i=i.rstrip()
       list2.append(i)

fp2=open("res.csv","a") #opening res file in append mode
flag=0

 for i in range(0,len(list1)): #iterating through lists

   if (i==len(list1)-1 and list1[i]!=list2[i]): #if total is different in both files
       fp2.write(list1[i-1]+","+str(abs(int(list1[i])-int(list2[i])))) #printing difference
       flag=1
   elif (list1[i]!=list2[i]): #if other lines are different
       fp2.write(list1[i-1]+","+list1[i]+","+list2[i-1]+","+list2[i]+"\n") #printing different lines
       flag=1

if (flag==0): #if there is no difference
   fp2.write("none")

 main() #calling main function
```

The output should be an excel table with a summary of the differences between the 2 files.The above code gives the difference in numbers between the files but if the number of lines is different, the output should also print the lines that are not in 1 file. I would appreciate any ideas to improve this code and help creating the code to compare a txt and csv file with an output of the difference on a excel spreadsheet.
Thank you.
* I am still new here so please let me know if I need to edit something or make a part of my question more clear.

Comment: first both of your files are csv. second, you seem to store all the items in a flat list, so you cannot possibly identify differences _per line_. Store lists of lists and compare instead.

Comment: hint: use `csv` module and `zip`.

Comment: you'd be better off using something like the csv module or pandas to compare the files, there are some complexities to csv formats that you aren't considering - for example fields in csv can contain a comma, but they need to be handled correctly..

Comment: So you are suggesting to create a list of both lists and look for differences per line then with zip? Just making sure I understand your answer correctly

Comment: Looks like csv module is the way to go. Yes Stael I was thinking about the fields problem too as a previous trial I had with the code was giving me everything different because of the commas...Did not really fix it though

Answer (score 0):

If both files contains the same type of data, I'd recommend to read both .csv and .txt data to pandas data table (after transformation).

After the reading you can easily operate with columns and rows of both datasets, i.e. find the difference between the two tables, and output this difference to any format you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Paul. I am sorry to ask but what do you mean after transformation? the conversion to both files into the pandas table?

Comment: I mean that you, as far as I get, need to transform your txt file to the format that is more similar to your csv file. After that you can read both files as like csv files with default pandas method read_csv() and work with two tables